# Reading huge file line by line in PHP

Tags: php

In Java I use Scanner to read text file line by line, so memory usage will be very low, because only one line is in memory once. Is there similar method in PHP?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use fseek, fgets

```
$handle = fopen("/tmp/uploadfile.txt", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $line = fgets($handle);
        // Process line here..
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

[Reading very large files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php/162263#162263)

Comment: This buffer thing bugs me too.  Will the buffer contain more than one line, and if so, how should we browse it ?  I used roughly this code, but removed this `4096` argument.  It also makes me wonder *what* would happen if a line is longer than those 4096

Comment: @KonradGałęzowski @Balmipour  just change `fgets($handle, 4096)` to `fgets($handle)`. PHP doc says about second `length` argument: *If no length is specified, it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line*. Answer should be also edited because question is about *Reading line by line*

Answer (score 4):

`fgets($fileHandle)` is what you're looking for. You get the file handle using `fopen("filename.txt", "r")`, and close it with `fclose($fileHandle)`.