# PHP Reading big file aborts site load

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents

I have a PHP script that loads content of a 175KB file but fails at the very top of the page. 
(It works with smaller file as it should be!!)
Here's the script snippet:

```
        if(!file_exists($sFile) || !is_readable($sFile)) {
            echo "<span style='color: #FF3333;'>Can not find/open file.</span><br />";
        } else {
            if(isset($_GET['content']) && is_writable($sFile)) {
                $hFile = fopen($sFile, "w");
                fwrite($hFile, urldecode($_GET['content']));
                fclose($hFile);
            }

            $sContent = file_get_contents($sFile);
        }
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo "?page=browser&path=" . dirname(realpath($sFile)); ?>" title="Back to <?php echo dirname(realpath($sFile)); ?>">
            &raquo; Back to <i><?php echo dirname(realpath($sFile)); ?></i>
        </a>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="edit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="file" value="<?php echo $sFile; ?>" />
            <textarea name="content" placeholder="..." style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 350px; resize: vertical;"><?php echo $sContent; ?></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Save changes" style="width: 100%;" />
        </form>
```

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php

It references timeout for fopen. I believe this is your issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the title of your question, I'd say PHP's `set_time_limit` would be your solution. However, after reading your question entirely, it also could be a memory limit set in place inside of `php.ini` or a hard limit that the server has.

You could try using `fopen()` and `fread()` instead, such as:

```
$f = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");
$s = "";
while (!feof($f)) {
  $s .= fread($f, 4096);
}
fclose($f);
// do something with the file contents inside of $s
```

You could also expand upon this example so that it echoes out the file as it reads it in.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, i just noticed the memory limit also exceeded the resources of my raspberry pi ;)