# Best way to read middle lines of big .log file for a period using php

Tags: php, file, readfile

I have log files more than 10GB. each line of a file start with date and time like

```
2014-12-12 18:17:56 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2014-12-12 18:17:57 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2014-12-12 18:17:58 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

2014-12-21 18:17:57 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2014-12-21 18:17:57 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2014-12-21 18:17:58 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2014-12-21 18:17:59 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want read and view the logs for a period 
example from start-date-time(2014-12-12 18:17:57) to end-date-time(2014-12-21 18:17:58)

I can explode file into array and do the task, but I need best solution with less memory usage.

Please help me on it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

4096 size in bytes to load into memory
Example:

```
<php    
$handle = fopen("/logfile.log", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        //Process buffer here..
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

[Reading very large files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php)