# How to read a big data (source file) line by line in PHP?

Tags: php, optimization

I am C++ programmer and trying my hand in PHP and found it is quite similar. I am trying to read a big source file using following code.

```
$filename = "sample.txt";    /* Having millions of records*/
$file_handle = fopen($filename, "r");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $line = fgets($file_handle);
  /* do some parsing on $line*/  
} 
fclose($file_handle);
```

But i found when number of records in input file is more than 1 million it crahes and there is no output. How can i fix or optimize the code?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php

Comment: Is there line breaks in your file? May be the first of fgets have to read the entire file.

Comment: On which line crashes your script?

Comment: I am browsing records so I am not sure at which line it is crashing but it crashes when input file is large.

Comment: Ok, but it crashes on fopen or after being entered in the loop?

Comment: After entering in the loop

Comment: You can add a line size limit to see if it is the problem: fgets($file_handle, $line_size_limit);

Comment: How much it should be? I am using 4096 is it too much or less?

Comment: make tests, try to determine from which size it crashes, and before that, if it is because there a too big line that your script crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71983/discussion-between-gael-and-user15662).

Comment: try to see some error log,  it can be a memory limit,  a timeout limit,  some error in your parser.  try remove your parse code and execute again to see if it's about the parser.

Comment: I am planning to increase RAM. After increasing RAM i will dig out further. Thanks