# Large File Should read line by line or load by file_get_content

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Currently, We are getting large file average size is **60 MB** .

Here, We have to ways in terms of file processing.

I have two option for doing this:

```
1. Use File_get_content
2. Use file line by line using fopen
```

My concern is, How we can save in terms on memory, speeding. So we can utilize resource better.

Another thing, If we use PHP generators (yield) will benefit in this case.

Kindly mentor on this.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php

Comment: oh perfect. Thanks