# Calculate Entry of Strings in Huge TXT file

Tags: php, duplicates

I have a huge file of aroung 7 GB in `.txt` format which I'm processing using this thread [Reading very large files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162176/reading-very-large-files-in-php/162263#162263).

The sample of the .txt file:

```
cat
dog
dog
mouse
cat
bird
dog
cat
...
```

Now, I need to organize this file into something like:

```
[cat] -> 3
[dog] -> 3
[mouse] -> 1
[bird] -> 1
```

Please guide where to search to solve this matter.
Thank you for your time and advices.

Comment: you did not explain your problem very well. What are you trying to do?

Comment: usually it involves opening a file, then reading the contents inside, then for gathering the count, you can use arrays. but then you need to start coding though

Comment: i'm trying to calculate the entry of unique lines in my file. E.g. cat is mentioned 3 times, dog -3, ...

Comment: I'm opening file, reading it line bu line, now I need to find a solution where to put lines and how to calculate the unique entry of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic example. It reads the text file, one line at a time and counts the lines that are the same.

```
<?php

$fn = fopen("my_very_large_file.txt","r");

$wordCounter = [];

while(!feof($fn)) {
    $word = fgets($fn);
    if (isset($wordCounter[$word])) {
        $wordCounter[$word]++;
    }
    else {
        $wordCounter[$word] = 1;
    }
}

fclose($fn);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($wordCounter);
echo "</pre>";
```

This will be exceedingly slow. However, that's not really a problem if you only need to use the code once. If you need it more often you need to find a way to speed it up.

Comment: Thank you, added some memory though )) ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); and goes smooth )

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-count-values.php)

So you have to convert your .txt into an array. The main probelem is I don't know if the file size would lead to an issue ...

To convert your file into an array you can use `explode()`.

If you need this file each time your script is executed, maybe store the result you need into a database. Thus you can simply get the data you need without executing all the file.

Have fun :)